# Blank subform: Unable to find a record, based off multiple fields

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010, subform

I've looked around for an answer to this issue, but have fond none.  Thank you in advance to anyone who's able to help.  I'm trying to look up records and alter them, based off multiple fields.  However, my form shows up blank.

I have a database with one to many links for the following tables: 
Sample->Set->Catch->Length->Diet (Key fields: SampleID, SetID, etc.)

Preliminary data is entered. I have additional data for some individuals to be entered into the Length and Diet tables. So, I created a form with combo boxes that allow the user to navigate to the correct fish by selecting: Date, Station, Set, Species, and Length.  So, when I select a date, I'm restricted to stations sampled on that day and so on.  I have a query string set up to restrict results to those matching the criteria entered into the combo boxes. My subform is based off the final query in this string (Query 5).  It's linked on the primary key field for the length table (LengthID).  All fine so far.

The issue: When I open my form and select values for each combobox, the subform remains blank.  However, I can run Query 5 from the sidebar at this point and it runs successfully. I could just enter data directly into the query, but it would be less streamlined and vulnerable to human error.

I've also tried opening my subform directly from the sidebar. When I do this, Access prompts me for the Date, Station, Set, Species, and Length.  Twice.  The form then shows up and all are fields blank including the LengthID field, which should be filled in (since I'm looking up an existing record).  I don't know why it prompts me twice, but I think that the subform isn't showing up in regular form view because the database sees the LengthID field as blank.

My combo boxes appear to navigate correctly to a given record. The query string my combo boxes and subform are based on all work when run directly.  But I can't enter data into my subform, presumably because the subform can't find the correct record even though the query it's based off of can find it just fine. I've  run out of troubleshooting ideas, any advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to achieve a query `WHERE` clause utilizing combo-boxes. There are many SO questions out there on this but this should get you going. Let me know if you run into trouble and I'll help you out.

I assume you have a linked parent/subform combo. This code would be on the parent form search button:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = " 1=1 "

If Not IsNull(cmbComboBox1) Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " AND Field1 = " & cmbComboBox1
End If

If Not IsNull(cmbComboBox2) Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " AND Field2 = " & cmbComboBox2
End If

If Not IsNull(cmbComboBox3) Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " AND Field3 = " & cmbComboBox3
End If

Me.Filter = strSQL
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: You can link master and child subform fields to comboboxes.